# Does there exist a universal random variable which can represent all events in a probability space?

Tags: probability, distributions

Given a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$, I know that for each event $A \in F$, we can define an indicator random variable $I_A$, then $A$ corresponds to $I_A=1$. I am wondering does there exist a "universal" random variable $X$, such that $\forall A \in F, A$ can be represented as $a \leq X \leq b$ for some $a$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}.$

Moreover, given a probability space, does the set of all random variables have any structure? If the "universal" random variable exists, is it unique and what is its role in this set?

Comment: The set of all random variables is the set of all $\mathfrak F$-measurable functions on $\Omega$ and it has lots of natural, useful structures.  The question of the existence of a "universal" variable is quickly and simply addressed by considering two different measurable sets and their complements: soon you will see it's impossible for certain combinations of those sets to correspond to intervals of real numbers.  That, unfortunately, doesn't leave one much to write about!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is simple but it's surprisingly hard to demonstrate rigorously: **when such a "universal random variable" $X$ exists, its image has *at most* two elements, which implies the sigma algebra $\mathfrak F$ has at most four events.**

**Let's begin by establishing definitions and notation.**

I understand that an event "$A$ can be represented as $a\le X \le b$" means $a=a(A)$ and $b=b(A)$ are numbers determined by $A$ and $X$ and that $A$ is the set of *all* outcomes for which the value of $X$ lies between $a$ and $b,$

$$A = X^{-1}([a,b]) = \{\omega\in\Omega\mid a \le X(\omega)\le b\}.$$

To avoid discussing infinities, compose $X$ with the (measurable, strictly increasing) function $x\to 1/(1 + \exp(-x))$ to assure the image of $X$ is in the interval $[0,1].$  This does not change the universal representation property of $X.$

**Now we can carry out the analysis.**

Suppose the image $X(\Omega)$ of $X$ contains more than two values.  Pick three of them and call them $x \lt y \lt z.$

Because $\{y\}$ is measurable, $B = X^{-1}(y)$ is a (nonempty) event. The complement $B^\prime = \Omega \setminus B$ also is an event. But

$$X(\omega) = y \in [x,z] \subseteq  [a(B^\prime), b(B^\prime)]$$

implies, by virtue of the representation property of $X,$ that $\omega\in B^\prime;$ that is, $\omega\notin B.$  This contradiction of the assumption $\omega\in B$ implies the original supposition is false: it is not possible for the image of $X$ to contain more than two values, *QED.*